# NullPointerExcetion on setting native Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception, look-and-feel

So I was tryig to make my Java GUI look better since I find the regular one very dull with this :

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the second I run it I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(FontDesignMetrics.java:217)
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:286)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1012)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1624)
    at sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper.reset(MenuItemLayoutHelper.java:126)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.<init>(SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.java:119)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.paint(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:498)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemUI.paint(SynthMenuItemUI.java:283)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemUI.update(SynthMenuItemUI.java:247)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5219)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1529)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1452)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5167)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4978)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(FontDesignMetrics.java:217)
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:286)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1012)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1624)
    at sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper.reset(MenuItemLayoutHelper.java:126)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.<init>(SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.java:119)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.paint(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:498)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemUI.paint(SynthMenuItemUI.java:283)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemUI.update(SynthMenuItemUI.java:247)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5219)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1529)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1452)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5167)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4978)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

But if I remove the LAF code all works good. What's the problem? I'm kind of a newbie working with GUI's since I'm more of a programming fan rather than a design.

Comment: As you're getting NPEs, something is probably not instantiated correctly.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException` is the problem.

Comment: What is your operating system? Are you setting the LAF on the Event Dispatch Thread or another thread?

Comment: You may wish to take a look at the examples in the Oracle tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: I'm using JFrame form so all objects and componentes are initialized automatically. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: You could also try setting -Dswing.defaultlaf=<your system LAF class name> on the command line, to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note that setting the PLAF is typically done before any components are created.  If there was a bug in the JRE such that setting it after that point caused an NPE, few other programmers would have noticed it.  See if you can reproduce the NPE when changing PLAF using the [nested layout code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).  It allows the user to change PLAFs after start-up.